# Debug GWT application in a remote browser

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, vmware

I try to debug the GWT app in a remote browser (located on other computer than Eclipse instance) for example in VMware environment. Unfortunately while opening address below there is no connection.

```
http://192.168.1.2:8888/app_test.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.2:9997
```

I've tried adding `-Dgwt.args="-bindAddress 0.0.0.0"` to *Arguments -> VM arguments* but the parameter seems to be unrecognized. Server still binds to localhost.

I use Google Eclipse plugin. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In eclipse open your debug configuration and add the param `-bindAddress 192.168.1.2` (replace the ip with the local ip address of your machine) to the `arguments > program arguments`. That's how we debug in virtual box.

Comment: z00bs, where do you suggest to add the'-bindAddress 192.168.1.2' param? When I try to put this into (Eclipse) `Run Configurations... -> Arguments -> Program arguments` I've got 'Unknown argument: -bindAddress'.

Comment: The solution for the problem mentioned above is to user GWT SDK version 2.0.4 (for 2.0.0 bindAddress won't work). z00bs - thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't know `bindAddress` requires a specific gwt version. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You no longer need to supply your local IP address.  You can just use `-bindAddress 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 8):

The steps I have used using Eclipse/GWT 2.4:

- Add the param "-bindAddress 0.0.0.0" in "Run Configuration|Arguments|Program Arguments" (Eclipse) on the server PC/Mac/Linux
- Server firewall: Open the port 9997 (in)
- Client firewell: Open the port 9997 (out)
- Lastly (and that was the step missing that prevent running/debugging). In your client Chrome browser, go the options (chrome://settings/extensions) and add the server IP address in the list of allowed hosts
- Start the server, it will display the proper URL

Answer (score 6):

For people struggling with GWT and Maven: The plugin accepts a parameter

```
 -Dgwt.bindAddress=0.0.0.0
```

other syntaxes did not work for me