# Testing GWT System in developmenet mode on 2 PC

Tags: networking, gwt, ip, p2p

I am using GWT and I need to test a page in development on 2 pc. On 1 pc, I am developing the system and I need to test something on another pc connected to the one I am developing the system.

The PC on which I am developing the system IP is 192.168.1.5

The PC on which I want to test the has IP 192.168.1.10

The network is OK because when I am pinging each one from both sides, I am getting 0 % packet loss

Currently, the adddress generated by GWT for the current page is
http://127.0.0.1:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
This URL is running on 192.168.1.5

I  am not that good in network. From 192.168.1.10, I am trying to access this
by typing the following but all has failed:

1. http://192.168.1.5:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
2. http://192.168.1.5:8888/BiddingSystem.html?gwt.codesvr=192.168.1.5:9997

Comment: What is the browser result for http://192.168.1.5:8888

Comment: hi, the result is simply page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [Debug GWT application in a remote browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944164/debug-gwt-application-in-a-remote-browser) or [how to check gwt application in dev mode from another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466193/how-to-check-gwt-application-in-dev-mode-from-another-computer/4469325#4469325) of any help?

Comment: Thanks lot for these two useful links