# Forwarding the ports for a GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

I need to share the output of my GWT application with a colleague over the Internet. So i  forwarded the ports 8080 for the Jetty server and 9999 for the code server.
Now when my friend tries to access the url `http://<my public ip address>:8080/myproject/show/mainpage?gwt.codesvr=<my public ip address>:9999` in his browser, the client loads up, but he gets the message "Plugin unable to connected to hosted mode server on..."
Any way to fix this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running also the Jetty server? I mean you need to run in debug mode your GWT project.

As i see now your college want to connect "in debug mode":

"?gwt.codesvr= [my public ip address] :9999"

1) You should start first to ping your IP, if it is ok you can go to step 2.

2) Then try to connect to your web application without jetty: 
http://[my public ip address]:8080/myproject/show/mainpage

3) Then if you guys want to debug like your college test and you follow the jetty server, you need to start jetty server GWT Dev Mode w/ o Jetty server, then in optimal situation your college can attach with his plugin to your jetty sever.

Good luck;)

Comment: Im running the hosted mode server, and it works fine on my machine with the url http://localhost:8080/myproject/show/mainpage?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9999. But my friend is unable to connect to the code server on port 9999. I have forwarded both the ports i.e 8080 and 9999 . Am i not already running in debug/development mode ?

Comment: first try it without debug mode ok? i mean with this URL:
" http://yourip:8080/myproject/show/mainpage " 
If it is good, than you can try the debug mode version and in this cause you shold run a jetty server....

Comment: Without debug mode, i.e. by directly visiting http://<my public ip>:8080/myproject/show/mainpage works for him. Its only when im running in development/debug mode is that he is getting plugin unable to connect to hosted mode server message in his browser

Comment: I didnt get the part where u say , u should run the Jetty Server. When  GWT development mode window opens, and i get the url http://localhost:8080/myproject/show/mainpage?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9999, doesnt that mean the inbuilt jetty server is already running ?

Comment: Yes gwt debug mode also start the jetty server, you have right, than my solution cant help, i will delete it... Gl. Maybe plugin delete and install can help, but have no more tought about this...

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution [from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944164/debug-gwt-application-in-a-remote-browser):

> In eclipse open your debug configuration and add the param
>   -bindAddress 192.168.1.2 (replace the ip with the local ip address of your machine) to the arguments > program arguments. That's how we
>   debug in virtual box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that too, but it didnt help