# GWT dev mode ipad

Tags: ipad, gwt

Hi, I'd like to run my `gwt` project in `dev mode` and open it on my i pad. How can I do this? I tried to replace the local-host part with my pcs ip address and open the website, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, the Jetty server binds on the **localhost** interface only, meaning that it will not serve request when the address is not **localhost** even if the specified IP is on the same machine.  To allow connection from other computers (or iPads) you need to modify this addres in the launch configuration.

Open your launch configuration:

```
Run --> Run Configurations... --> Web Application --> [YourApplication]
```

Open the Arguments tab and in the first text box (Program arguments) add the following argument:

**`-bindAddress [your ip address]`**

```
ex: -bindAddress 192.168.1.200
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944164/debug-gwt-application-in-a-remote-browser)

Answer (score 2):

There is NO WAY to use the dev mode for iOs, because there is no dev-mode plugin for iOS.

You can enable the [Super Dev Mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode). This will enable a really fast compiler.

**update**
As mentioned: `-bindAddress 0.0.0.0` may be helpful to bind the jetty to any IP.

Answer (score 0):

Your ipad and the system must be connected via Network (LAN).

Comment: Someone at work tested that. (he opened another side) Connection is there.

Comment: Sorry, is ipad and system both are part of the same network ?

Comment: I think so. O__o Cause we could reach my computer via other commands.

Comment: Think I can't reach the server.